# how do I save all files onto my local computer

Tags: web, save, notepad++

I have a website up and running.  I have Notepad++ on my local computer.  I can edit my website in real time using Notepad++.  I now would like to save "my website" on my local computer as a backup.  What is the easiest way to save all of the files using Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some type of control panel with your web hosting. From within the control panel find the file manager, navigate to your httpdocs directory (or where-ever the public files of your site are located) make a zip of that folder and download it.

Option 2 is

- get an FTP client like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org)
- get FTP connection details from your hosting provider or via your control panel
- connect and download the httpdocs folder to your local computer

Good luck!